# Use windows 10 instead of windows server to host services

Tags: windows-10, windows-server-2012, hosting

I need to host a website and 3 windows services. I am placing that computer into a building that has fiber optic (internet speed is 1000 Mbps download and 200 Mbps upload!). Anyways is it bad if I use windows 10 as the operating system to host these services? Should I install windows server 1012 to be safe? What could go wrong if I install windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most definitely can host a website on Windows 10.  You say "services," but dont mention what they are.  Assuming these services come with, or can be installed on Windows 10, then it will work.

Server versions of Windows are designed to handle more concurrent users than desktop versions.  Also, they prioritize background tasks over user tasks.  You can customize Windows 10 to prioritize background tasks, if you want.

As long as your hardware can handle the load and you arent exceeding the software liceneses (if any), there is no reason you cant use Windows 10.

Comment: Regarding software licenses I guess I can install sql server on windows 10 so I should be good with that. And the windows services they only runs some tasks every 2 hours or so in order to automate things. I guess I will install windows 10 then. Thanks for the help!